# How to design tables for a complicated messaging system between two different entities?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, orm, relational-database

I'm developing a web application that contains a messaging system. The web application has a basic entity (users), users can own another entity in the application (companies), each company may have more than one user (think of it as employees of a team). A user might not necessarily have a relation with a company. A company must have a relation with at least one user.

I'm trying to create a messaging (more of an intra-application email system rather than a chat) system within the application. However, the messaging system has certain restrictions on who is allowed to send messages to whom:

- Users can send messages to companies
- Companies can send messages to users
- Companies can send messages to companies

We will have two different inboxes/outboxes for users and companies. Meaning inside the dashboard, if a user owns a company, he will have a page to his own user inbox, and a page for his company inbox.

My problem is with determining the entity of the sender and receiver and I can't seem to find a good maintainable table design for the messages table. 
Below is the structure for the users table, companies table and company_users table:

[image: Users Table]

[image: Companies Table]

[image: Company_Users Table]

The design I had in mind (which after implementation I don't believe is the best possible design) is to have a `sender_user_id` field and a `sender_company_id` field for each row. If the `sender_user_id` is null, while `sender_company_id` is set. This would mean that the sender of this message is a company and vice versa. The same thing for the receiver. Below is the design for the messages table

[image: Messages Table]

Does anyone have a better design in mind? Something more maintainable maybe? This is currently relationship hell in the backend. Thank you.

Comment: So users cannot send messages to users?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account Microsoft ExchangeServer and its single instance storage as an example, I think the thing you're missing is pointers.

If your use cases were wound back to a single sender can send a single message to a single receipient then I think your schema would be almost bang on.

If you want a person (e.g. Company Admin) to be able to send a message to all members of a company then what you're actually saying is:

"I'd like the Company Admin to send pointers to the message to all current members of the company".

What I mean is that when they send the message, they're actually creating message_pointers to the original message.  That way, when a recipient deletes "the message", all they're actually doing is deleting their individual reference to that message.

Does that help?